# if s and t are positive numbers, what are the values of m? m|5^s7^t

Tags: number-theory

$m|5^s7^t$

Task: Please find the values of $m$ if $s$ and $t$ are positive whole numbers. I have tried using $m\cdot k = 5^s7^t$ but I could not understand.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Factors of $5^s7^t$ are of the form $5^a7^b$ where $0\le a\le s$ and $0\le b\le t$

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is $s$ and $t$ given or $s, t$ are free and you want to find all $m$ which is a factor of $5^s7^t$ for some $s, t > 0$

Answer (score 0):

$$m \mid 5^s \cdot 7^t$$

Then the prime factorization of $m$ contains $5^i$ or $7^j$ or some combination of both.

$$m=5^i \cdot 7^j $$
where $0\leq i \leq s$ and $0 \leq j \leq t$